# Why do Wrestlers not step on their opponents backs, when running the ropes?

Tags: pro-wrestling

In Wrestling, it is often seen, that down opponents turn from their backs to their bellies, when an opponent is running the ropes, which prompts their opponent to jump over them rather than just stepping on them.

Is there an in-universe or kayfabe reason for this? It seems like an unwritten law and other than, they might roll an ankle, I can't really think of an explanation.

See [here](https://youtu.be/14ho7lz6VsI?t=299) for an example.

Comment: Meta question: [Would pro wrestling be considered on topic?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/would-pro-wrestling-be-considered-on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the storyline aspects of entertainment wrestling ("in-universe or kayfabe reasons") and not the sporting aspects.

Comment: I think it is a decent question but the answer is probably more simplistic than you think.   I worked out with a large group of wrestlers.   These guys are big (not naturally), they are good at learning routines (think big gymnast), but these are not the most athletic guys in the world and the fake bulk makes that even worse.   So other than not want to really hurt the guy on the ground it would be because if you are bouncing off ropes and running and stepping on someone the chance of you turning an ankle, tripping, whatever... looking like a clown - pretty high.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an in-universe or kayfabe reason for this?

No reason in particulary, i think. Wrestling is all about entertainment. They could do that, step on their opponents backs, because the WWE Superstar, Finn Ballor, his special move is climb to the top rope and flyes with the feet into the chest of their opponent.